# Object not being able to map to POJO class

Tags: java, gson, pojo

I am getting a response, which I converted to Pojo class with one field of type Object. Now when I am trying to cast the Object type to another Pojo class its throwing the error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to SecondClass
```

Code :

```
FirstClassResponse firstClassResponse = (FirstClassResponse) convertJSONToObject(firstClassResponseJson, FirstClassResponse.class);

//jsonToObject method 
public static Object convertJSONToObject(String jsonRequest, Class objectClassType) throws Exception {
    Object object = gson.fromJson(jsonRequest, objectClassType);
    return object;
}
```

Here, firsClass object when printed gives following result :

```
FirstClassResponse [modifiedResponse=null, response={id=123, username=abc, balance=0.0, currencycode=EUR, created=2021-03-30 16:31:54, agent_balance=0.0, sessionid=123}]
```

**Now, the error happens in the following line :**

```
SecondClassResponse modifiedResponse = (SecondClassResponse) firstClassResponse.getResponse();
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to SecondClassResponse
```

I am sharing the POJO for FirstClassResponse and SecondClassResponse :

```
public class FirstClassResponse{

    private SecondClassResponse modifiedResponse;

    private Object response;
    //getter, setter 
}

public class SecondClassResponse{

    private String id;
    private String username;
    private double balance;
    private String currencycode;
    private String created;
    private double agent_balance;
    private String sessionid;
    //getter, setter

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Object response;
```

Make this a SecondClassResponse, not an Object.  With it being an Object, GSON doesn't know that this should be a SecondClassResponse, so it just shoves the map in there as a Map, which obviously can't be cast.

The entire point of using GSON is to turn everything into specific objects so you can use it in a more Java like way.  If you store something as an Object when converting from GSON, you're almost always doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

That `FirstClassResponse` is completely superfluous; use `SecondClassResponse` instead.
Just look at the JSON ...and then explain to me how to map as `FirstClassResponse`?

And you've not even object-relational mapping (as the GSON converter does), but you're parsing.

Comment: I have hidden some part of my code. But what I actually want to ask is why the Object type is not getting typecasted to SecondClassResposne

Comment: @arqam I find it hard to follow you in general, but as a matter of fact... if you want nested objects, you need to provide nested JSON; while the JSON is flat, this will never result in nested objects. `Object` might even be a rather unfortunate return type; better use generics - or instead do ORM.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps gson.fromJson cannot convert the attribute class of the class before. You can try to take out firtClassResponse.getResponse() and do the conversion separately